# when deploying debezium/postgres image for the CDC using kafka container is not getting started

Tags: postgresql, openshift, debezium

The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.
The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
Data page checksums are disabled.
initdb: could not change permissions of directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data": Operation not permitted
fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4oqY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you edit your post to describe a clear, specific problem, question and desired outcome? See [how to ask: minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Is the question related to deploying the postgres image to the OpenShift?

Comment: Yes..It's related to deploying debezium postures image on open shift for achieving CDC using kafka

Comment: Debezium postgres image

Comment: Please check this PR - https://github.com/debezium/docker-images/pull/82 It contains a postgres image derived from openshift enabled images. ry to build and deploy it. It might resolve your problem.